# Photo Edge Detection using a mask on iPhone

Tags: iphone, selection, photo, edge-detection

I'm looking for code to be able to contrast detect edges in a photo.

Basically, the user will roughly paint the mask with their finger on Iphone, iPod or iPad. Then the code would detect the edges and adjust the mask to the edges.

Thanks for your help!

http://www.image-y.com/before.jpg
http://www.image-y.com/after.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I recommend taking a look at **OpenCV** (which is also compilable on iOS (take a look at https://github.com/aptogo/OpenCVForiPhone)). A nice addition (with explanations) could be provided by this article http://b2cloud.com.au/tutorial/uiimage-pre-processing-category.

When having gained a basic understanding of what you can do with OpenCV, I'd personally try to do some kind of **thresholding** and **contour detection** (take a look at cv::findContours). Afterwards you could filter the found contours by using the given input by your user.